# Unable to set up vscode to practice python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Today just for practice I have downloaded and installed vscode.
I saw a tutorial on the installation of vscode for python and followed the procedure exactly.
But upon completion, whenever any python code is running, it is throwing an exception.

Eg:- A simple code I was trying to run like
def greet():
print 'Hello world'

But the terminal is throwing an exception saying "Invalid Syntax"

I really don't know where I am going wrong
If anyone of you has experience working on vscode and is willing to help then please tell me what I can do

The extensions I have enabled:-
**Code Runner,**
**Python**

Earlier the python extension was not enabled, but even after enabling it, the error is still there

*[Please have a look at the problem I am facing in setting things up with vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dW49.jpg)*

Comment: You're in the terminal below and you need to exit from it first otherwise it puts runner code there which is invalid Python. So please press CTRL+Z after putting your cursor next to `>>>` and then run again.

Comment: @MustafaAydın maybe `CTRL+D` will be better.or enter `exit()` in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should not type in `python` in the terminal.

Because the Python Extension only sends some commands to the terminal and then executes them.

If you type `python` in the terminal you will enter into the `interactive mode`, and the commands which intended to be executed in the terminal will be executed in the `python interactive mode`, and lead to `SyntaxError`.

So, you can get out of the `python interactive mode` through `Ctrl+Z` shortcut or kill the terminal and then execute the commands in a new terminal.